# How do I make a Project Always build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a dummy project that just runs a bunch of post build stuff.  I want this project to run every time I build, but it will only run if something has change (which I know is very very useful by default)

So my question is, is there a way to configure a project to always build regardless of whether or not something has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a VC++ Makefile project, and have it depend on all other projects in the solution.  It will build every time.